# How to assign sample weight for regression problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, forecasting, lightgbm

I'm trying to model a forecasting problem where I'm trying to forecast for the following month. I am using `LightGBM` Regressor class for it and it giving me a decent result in terms of actual Vs. predicted and `mean_absolute_error`. There is one category of samples in my training set that I really want to improve on and bring down the `mean_absolute_error` and I was thinking if I can penalize the model when it is wrong on that category of samples I might be able to achieve better results. Is there a way to pass sample weights to `LGBMRegressor` or any `sklearn`'s regression class where perhaps the cost function is `weighted sum of square` cost function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you pass a `sample_weight` to the LGBMRegressor().fit() method. See [documentation on LGBMRegressor](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html), section Methods:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't realize that it was to be passed in the `fit` method. Do you know how know how `LightGBM` uses these weights? Will simple the `Sum of sqaure` error to weighted `Sum of Sqaure` by weighing or multiplying each sample error to its respective weight in the array?

Comment: No, I don't think its that straitforward, according the the LightGBM paper https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/6449f44a102fde848669bdd9eb6b76fa-Paper.pdf it has something to do with individual sample gradients, though I failed to understand the details.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I'll take a look.